# How to find average and power of signal expressed by fourier series

Tags: complex-analysis, discrete-mathematics, fourier-series, signal-processing

I need to find the average and the power of this signal:

$$x(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{-k}e^{j2{\pi}kn}$$

The problem is that the summation starts at 1 and not at 0, and a part of that how can I find the average of a signal expressed in this way?

Comment: See this article on [Parseval's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem#Statement_of_Parseval's_theorem)

Comment: yea , but the sum start from 1 an goes to inf so idk what kind of series it is

Comment: It's still a Fourier series where the coefficients are zero for $k<1$.

Comment: so x(n) is a periodic signal of period 1 ? @MarkViola

Comment: but the fourier series of a discrete periodic signal isn't form 0 to N-1 wher N is the period ?

Comment: oh sorry yes , we use n for discrete signals

Comment: You can evaluate the series in closed form.  Have you pursued that way forward?

Comment: how ?  get a finite result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
x(n)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}e^{i2\pi kn}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{e^{i2\pi n}}{2}\right)^k\\\\
&=\frac{e^{i2\pi n}}{2-e^{i2\pi n}}\\\\
&=\frac{2e^{i2\pi n}-1}{5-8\cos(2\pi n)}
\end{align}$$

Can you proceed now?

Comment: well now can we has written the signal in this way i canl find the power by doing the summation of the squared signal? or this is the transform ?